# JackRabbit repository on disk

Tags: java, jackrabbit

I'm working on a java project using JackRabbit 2.0.
What I want is to create a repository on my disk to store some datas. Currently the only thing I found is how to stock in memory using TransientRepository() but it's not what I want to do.
I don't find how to create a repository on disk using JackRabbit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Jackrabbit Oak? It supports MongoDB based store and tar file based store.
I see your other question which refers to Oak and I am assuming you have a legacy app with Jackrabbit.

Comment: My internship superviser advise me to use JackRabbit 2.0 so I searched this way but I will try again with Oak and arguy to use it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have modify your repository.xml  to have a local file storage. You have some options there. Please have a look at: http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ